# Force Runtastic to show kJ instead of Cal

Tags: applications, fitness

How can one make Runtastic to show energy unit in kilo Joules instead of Calories?

Comment: You will need to dig through that app's settings to see if this is possible.  If the app doesn't provide this feature there is nothing you can do.